# How to update external jar file without breaking everything with gradle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, jar

When updating an external jar file which contains breaking changes, so the code at certain points will have errors (which happens and is fine), I am unable to build my project via gradle, thus EVERY import from the jar shows up in my IDE as an error (Intellij).

This makes it super hard to actually see where the errors are, since ALL imports from the jar, even though all those classes are in there show up as "errors", since build failure means gradle simply wont import the jar at all...

The end result is that my IDE shows things like this (removed package name for security reasons):

[image]

All of those model.entity classes ARE in the jar, but gradle wont import them because the build process stops at the first syntax error in the code...

Is there any way around this? How to refactor large code bases without relying on the error messages inside the gradle console (which there might be a LOT of).

I'd like to import the jar first THEN fix the syntax errors? Maybe a different gradle command? I'm simply using "clean build"

Comment: Did you try refreshing the Gradle dependencies from the right sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 aspects here.

1. grade
2. IDE (appears to be Intellij) - imports the gradle to create project. unless on auto refresh, requires manual reimport (refresh button) when there are changes in gradle files

in your scenario, initial state is gradle build works, Intellij works fine

you replace the dependency with 'breaking' change.

1. gradle `build` - will fail at compile stages as code is yet to the fixed
2. IntelliJ - still is not seeing new dependency. click the `re-import`

The import will always succeed unless there are errors in .gradle files
After import IDE will now reflect new dependency